# First program in Swift - HelloWorld

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have some issue with my first code in Swift, when I'm running it, it seems fine, but it shows e.g. Hello Optional "(name)" instead of Hello (name).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


  @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var sayHelloButton: UIButton!

  @IBAction func sayHelloAction(sender: AnyObject)

  {

    let name = nameTextField.text

    if name!.isEmpty {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter a name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {

        helloLabel.text = "Hello \(name)!"
    }
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    setupUI()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func setupUI() {
    helloLabel.text = "Hello There!"
    helloLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    helloLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    nameTextField.placeholder = "Enter your name"
    sayHelloButton.setTitle("Say Hello", forState: .Normal)

  }
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Doms.

Comment: I know that reading documentation is uncool, but it's worth it to read at least the chapter [The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) of Swift Language Guide.

Comment: Can you update your question to include what you've just tried, and where the new crash is happening? I'd also suggest commenting out the alert-related code at first, and just doing a `print()` statement instead, to more easily isolate where the problem is.

Comment: @vadian thanks, but I've ready it already :)

Answer (score 6):

In Swift you have a type called `Optional`. This is used to express nullability. You need to do what is called unwraping the optional. I will discourage you from force unwrapping `!` it will cause your app to crash. You can unwrap an optional value using the `if let` statement:

```
@IBAction func sayHelloAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let name = nameTextField.text where !name.isEmpty {
        helloLabel.text = "Hello \(name)"
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter a name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, after trying your solution xCode shows " Optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean". Any help?

Comment: There's a more effective syntax for the optional binding: `if let name = nameTextField.text where !name.isEmpty {`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when I was just learning Swift myself, and it tends to pop out in all sorts of places. For instance, I couldn't understand why one of my tableview columns always said "0" instead of "1" or "2". It was in fact saying "O"ptional!

The simplest solution is to `guard` everything everywhere. That way the compiler knows you've checked that it's not nil, and "unwraps" the value for you. so instead of:

```
let name = nameTextField.text
```

just do a:

```
guard let name = nameTextField.text else { return }
```

Replace that `return` with something more appropriate. From that point on, `name` is the string and won't have the `Optional(theThingYouReallyWanted)` any more.

note: as I said at the start, this has a habit of showing up in weird places. If you bind Optionals into things like text fields or table columns, you'll see it when you don't expect it. I strongly suggest making getter/setter properties for all UI work, and using the guard to unwrap as above and instead of `return` hand back an empty string or something similar.

Comment: Hi! After adding 'guard' before let name, app starts and then it crashes.

Line with guard let name = nameTextField.text is highlighted on green and it's showing Thread:1 breakpoint 1.1. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

You get the `Optional("")` because the optional value is not unwrapped. You need to put a `!` after the object and you won't get the `Optional("")` bit any more. I would show you the code but you haven't shown us the `print()` statement. I made some sample ones below that I think would replicate the problem, though I haven't tried them.

```
var value:String?
value = "Hello, World"

print("The Value Is \(value)") // Prints "The Value Is Optional(Hello, World)"    
print("The Value Is \(value!)")// Prints "The Value Is Hello, World"
```

Comment: No. OP needs to *safely unwrap* as explained in Kyle's upvoted answer from February. You shouldn't use force-unwrapping in this case and certainly not tell a beginner that's what they need. Please read the Swift manual.